# Change input placeholder on global state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I am in the mid of building a shopping cart demo, I am almost done for my purposes however I faced a frustrating bug that I can't seem to get around

[image: The box in the middle is supposed to be an input field]

The box in the middle is supposed to be an input field so that if a user requests a large number of products they can easily type it down instead of incrementing.

When I type in a number it reflects correctly and produces the desired change.

However, if I typed in a number and later used the (+ / -) buttons the placeholder value doesn't seem to change.

Here is my code

```
 <div className="prod-count">
       <button className="plus" onClick={()=> onIncrement(product.id)}>+</button>
       <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> handleValue(product.id, valueExtracter(e))} className="num-box" placeholder={product.quantity}/>
       <button className="minus" onClick={()=> onDecrement(product.id, product.quantity)}>-</button>
 </div>
```

and here is the onChange function

```
    const valueExtracter = (e) => {
        return parseInt(e.target.value)
    }

    //handle value will only run if input is a number 
    const handleValue = (id, value) => {
        if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0){
            dispatch(setQuantity(id, value))
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure the action gets dispatched correctly and I can see it in the total values, so the (product.quantity) value changes, but the placeholder doesn't get updated

**One Last thing: The desired effect gets applied once I switched placeholder to value, however, once the component is created with the value of (1) the end user cannot erase this (1) and needs to select and overwrite it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make the value extracter accept any thing and turn to an empty string and pass it to the handle value

```
const valueExtracter = (e) => {
    let value = parseInt(e.target.value)
    if (isNaN(value)) return ''
    else return value
}

//handle value will only run if input is a number 
const handleValue = (id, value) => {
    if (value === '' || value > 0){
        dispatch(setQuantity(id, value))
    }
}
```

switched the placeholder to value since it can accept an empty string now

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e)=> handleValue(product.id, valueExtracter(e))} className="num-box" value={product.quantity}/>
```

if the reducer catches an empty string it'll multiply it by the price which would turn the displayed price to 0 so I made a fix for that too

```
<div className="prod-price">
     {itemPrice >= product.price ? `$ ${itemPrice.toFixed(2)}` : <span className="disabled-price">$ {product.price}</span>}
</div>
```

the displayed price will display in red instead if the quantity is '' since '' * a number will return 0

and finally
the total quantity and price will be updated via the reducer and if the products quantity is '' it'll turn the totals to a string so I can error check on submition and alert the user to write a quantity or delete the item

so I wrote this in the reducer to get every thing back if the user decides to use the increment value once the field has beenn cleared "" + 1 = "1" , so this was fixed by checking in the educer function

```
 case "UPDATE_CART": 
        const indexToUpdate = cartCopy.findIndex(product => product.id === action.id)
        // if condition checks for when the item is set to '' to reset its value to 1
        if (cartCopy[indexToUpdate].quantity === ''){
            let itemReadded = {
                ...cartCopy[indexToUpdate],
                quantity: 1
            }
            newCart = [
                ...cartCopy.slice(0,indexToUpdate),
                itemReadded,
                ...cartCopy.slice(indexToUpdate + 1)
            ]
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: newCart ,
                totalAmount: totals(newCart).amount,
                totalQty: totals(newCart).qty,
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just trade the placeholder for value.
EDIT: 'I would trade minus button position with the increment one' its seens more user friendly

```
<div className="prod-count">
       <button className="minus" onClick={()=> onDecrement(product.id, product.quantity)}>-</button>
       <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> handleValue(product.id, valueExtracter(e))} className="num-box" value={product.quantity}/>
       <button className="plus" onClick={()=> onIncrement(product.id)}>+</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks, my prime language is rtl so i'm kinda wired that way, anyways found a fix, my main issue with value was that i cant delete the initial value 1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the value prop

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={(e)=> handleValue(product.id, valueExtracter(e))} 
  className="num-box"
  value={product.quantity}
  placeholder={product.quantity}
/>
```

Also, you may not need placeholder prop with value prop there.